# Can I use Activity.finish() to set result of activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to set result of my `Activity` depending on whether user made some changes on the screen. I've implemented it as follows:

```java
override fun finish() {
    setResult(if (presenter.hasChanges) RESULT_OK else RESULT_CANCELED)
    super.finish()
}
```

But I have a doubt that `finish()` method is called every time corresponding `Activity` finishes.

Documentation [says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=en#finish()) that I can call this method but does not specify whether Android Framework calls it too to close current `Activity`.

So my question is: can I rely on `finish()` method to set result of my `Activity` or there is a better way to do that?

Comment: you can also call `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Well if the user has to navigate to another activity he has to do the on-screen UI buttons or actions.. So handle it there rather than override finish as you might run the risk of using it in the same activity which does not need to that function.

Comment: @sanjeev I'm not sure I got you right. What do you mean?

Comment: why you are not setting result in `onPause()` or `onStop()` ?

Comment: Firstly analyse where you navigate to the previous or next activity, use a boolean to check whether changes made. Then use it only where required.

Comment: @Hanzala as I know `onPause()` and `onStop()` are called after `finish()` so setting result there will have no effect.

Comment: why you are willing to set result in finish()?
 you have to set that from which point you want to finish or go back to pervious activity

Comment: I don't want to handle all the ways for going back: back button, up button and so on. I want the one centralized solution for all cases. And `finish()` seems to fit that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `finish()` is completely fine in your case. You are doing it in a good way.

But `setResult()` will pass result to calling activity, only if you called current activity as `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: You mean _overriding_ `finish()`?

Comment: @DaniilPopov Yes. You got it correctly. So when you will call activity using startActivityForResult() it will pass result to caller, and if called uisng startActivity() result will be ignored. So you are completely fine by overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `finish()` method is called by the android system on its own like `onStart()` or `onCreate()` do. How about writing the same code in `onDestroy()`?

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    setResult(if (presenter.hasChanges) RESULT_OK else RESULT_CANCELED)
    super.onDestroy() //or finish()
}
```

Comment: It has no meaning because setting result after `finish()` has called has no effect

Comment: Also there is no guarantee that onDestroy will always be called

Comment: `onDestroy()` is called when you finish an activity, I believe.
And regarding `onDestroy()` not being called, `onDestroy()` is called when system is low on resources and kills your app or when somebody calls `finish()` on your activity. That should include our use case or most use cases, right?